# Adding member to approval team

Tags: marketing-cloud, approval-process, content-builder

I have a user whose approvals for content builder are not coming through. I suspect it is because she is not in a workflow team. When I try to add the user to the workflow team, it doesnt find her in the search, even though she is a part of the business unit.

Anyone had this issue before or know how to solve this?

Comment: Can you check if she is Active Salesforce User?

Comment: She isnt an active salesforce user. Dont think this is the problem as I can add people to teams that are not integrated Salesforce Users